# Is there a way to add a title or a caption to the drawing using graph_tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

At least some workaround would be appreciated. I am trying to save the figures as pdfs and then use it with latex as an animation. If there is a way to automatically add captions that will be really helpful as I am going to have about 50-60 figures.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is possible natively, but you can put the graph drawn by graph-tool in a matplotlib Figure() using the mplfig option in graph_draw(). With that you have access to all the flexibility of matplotlib around your graph.